# I keep getting an error in my Node.js server: "__dirname is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I just started learning Node.js, and i'm stuck on trying to set up a middleware for static resources. When trying to do this i just keep getting a **"__dirname not defined"** error in my IDE. Although no errors show up in command line, i know it isn't working because my site still says **"cannot GET /"**. I also know that "__dirname" is recognised by my IDE because when i console.log(__dirname) it shows the directory in command line. But for some reason it wont work with the "app.use" function.

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

/*this won't work*/
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));


app.listen(3000, function() {
           console.log(__dirname);
           })
```

i've also tried

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Your IDE can't see it because Node exposes that for you. The IDE only knows what it sees in your file. The fact that `/` doesn't work is a different issue.

Comment: What IDE are you using? Some IDEs don't understand the concept of implicit globals. You can just ignore those errors and your code should still run fine.

Comment: As for the `Cannot GET /`, you need an `index.html` file in your `public` directory.

Comment: Please add your project folder structure

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Oh thanks, i didn't realise it needed to be named "Index". That worked.

Comment: Recommend you get a smarter IDE. I use Atom w/Nuclide for JS, YMMV.